# Javascript not working when jquery is added

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am new to javascript n jquery. I used javascript along with jquery on my script tag.When jquery is not added, the javascript works fine,but when a jquery function is added, the script is not working.....shall i convert both to javascript or both to jquery or am i missing anything.Here is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getLocations() {
    $.post('@Url.Action("getLocations","Home")', { 'id': $("#cities").val() },
        function (data) {
            $("#loca").html(data).show();

        });
}

$(function () {
$('.submit').on('click', function () {
    var ck = "";
    var city = $("#cities option:selected").text();
    var location = $("#loca option:selected").text();
    alert(city+"and"+location)
}
});

</script>
```

here i am loading location based on the city selected.Its works fine when the onclick is not there,But when added ,location are not loading n the function is not calling.I have tried by butting alert inside it.Do i need do any thing else for both to work....Thank You

Comment: Did you add your jquery references to your <head> element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you forgot a `)`

```
$(function () {

    $('.submit').on('click', function () {
       ...
    })   // <---
});
```

if you properly indent the code blocks and if you look on the javascript console, this kind of errors become easier to be detected. Just adopt an [indent style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) and write code adhering to it.

Comment: Should be a semicolon there too; In this case I don't think it's necessary but should still be there.

Comment: A semicolon is not strictly necessary if followed by a closing `}`