# jQuery-line $(this).nextAll('.toggled:first') works in Stack Snippet and JSFiddle, but not on site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't figure out why the following code doesn't work on my site, but works great on *JSFiddle*, as well as here in a *Stack Snippet*:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $
    $(".toggler").click(function() {
      $(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
    }).next().hide();
    $(".togglerLink").click(function() {
      $(this).nextAll('.toggled:first').fadeIn("fast");
    });
  });
})(jQuery)
```

```css
.toggler {
  color: orange;
  text-decoration: underline
}
.toggler:hover {
  color: orange;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
The <a class="togglerLink" href="#link">link</a> here, has a destination inside the Toggler.
<br>
<br>

<p class="toggler">Toggle here.</p>
<div class="toggled">In JSFIddle, or in a Stack Snippet (SO), this code is working fine. Even when the Toggler is closed, the link automatically opens the Toggle that contains it destination. --- So, then what could be going wrong, implementing this into a website?
  <br>
  <br><span id="link" style="color:green">Link-destination.</span>
  <hr>
</div>
```

What is not working then is:

- The link doesn't automatically opens the required Toggle using `$(this).nextAll('.toggled:first').fadeIn("fast");`. Thus, the link leads nowhere when the Toggler is closed.

Still working:

- Manual toggling with *jQuery* `$(this).next().slideToggle("slow");
  }).next().hide();` still works fine.
- Also, the link `<a class="togglerLink" href="#link">link</a>` works fine when the toggler is opened manually.

## Literature look-up

I tried to kill this bug by looking up similar posts:

- [→](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075461): Is *jQuery* included twice? → I think not.
- [→](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21993692): Don't forget about some brackets.
- [→](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17813535): Use the *jQuery `(document).ready(`-function*.

  - Perhaps the weird behavior has something to do with the *brackets* or the *jQuery document ready function $(*?

Normally, I load my jQuery-codes in between `<script type="text/javascript">(function($){$(document).ready(function(){$`...`;});})(jQuery)</script>`.

However, here, in this "problematic" code, I **have** to use `});})(jQuery)` to close. Thus with 1 `;` less up front.

## Debugging

---

- *Firefox 35.0.1.*

**jQuery-1.10.2.min.js :1** (this also occurs on test pages without the "problematic" code)

> Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead

☞ **jQuery-1.10.2.min.js :5** → This only shows when clicking the link, when the Toggler is closed!

> Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.

- *Chrome 40.0...* (View > Developer > Developer Tools > Console) gives no warnings.

Comment: Hi Vincent. When you isolate a piece of code and it works, then the common cause of it not working on your website is that something else goes wrong on your website. You should check your JavaScript console for errors (e.g. in Chrome: View > Developer > Developer Tools > Console). If that's entirely clean, you got a valid problem. If it's not, you have to solve those errors first.

Comment: @T.S., thanks a lot for your kind and helpful reply. I have added debugging info to my post, and also try to narrow the warnings down, by creating several test pages as controls. I hope to specify a related warning in a bit.

Comment: I would try and approach this by first of all checking whether the used jQuery selectors deliver the expect results. Maybe your page structure differs from that in the working example ever so slightly … and a single element not found due to that could prevent a whole script from working as expected.

Comment: @CBroe, thanks for your constructive comment. Manual toggling with jQuery still works fine. Do you mean then to check if the `.toggled:first` can be reached via jQuery on the site? Might I ask for a suggestion on what to do? Much thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes, try putting a `console.log($(this).nextAll('.toggled:first').length);` right above that line, to see if that actually “catches” any elements. If the output is 0, then that means jQuery has not found any elements for that selector at this point. And if that’s not it, proceed by checking other parts that might be relevant where elements are selected the same way.

Comment: @CBroe, That seems like a very adept tool in this case. When following your protocol, **the console output is 0 indeed**! I wonder what's going wrong there?

Comment: Vincent, if you use the code from my answer for the click-function for `.togglerLink`, what do you get for `console.log($(id).parents('.toggled'))`?

Comment: Whether I put that line right above `var id = $(this)...` or right above `$(id).parents('.toggled')...`, there seems to be **no console output**, however your answer has cracked the bug! Thanks a lot! I will read your `//comments...` to understand it better!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nextAll()` function only checks for elements on the same or deeper node-level in the DOM.

So your code will work with the following HTML structure:

```
The <a class="togglerLink" href="#link">link</a> here, has a destination inside the Toggler.
<div class="toggled">
    <span id="link" style="color:green">Link-destination.</span>
</div>
```

But not with something like this:

```
<div>
    The <a class="togglerLink" href="#link">link</a> here, has a destination inside the Toggler.
</div>
<div class="toggled">
    <span id="link" style="color:green">Link-destination.</span>
</div>
```

The solution is to have a more specific selector in your jQuery code:

```
$(".togglerLink").click(function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('href'); // will return '#link', which we can use as ID selector
    $(id).parents('.toggled').fadeIn("fast"); // The $(id) will select the element with ID 'link' and the 'parents()' will select the parent(s) with class 'toggled'.
});
```

Comment: Very nicely done [T.S.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1226267/t-s),  thanks a lot! If you would like to have a double-credits-treat, feel free to post an improved answer with the code you debugged at: [Hyperlink to “hidden” content (a certain #id) inside a jQuery-Toggler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28520724/).